# How can I click a button in php DomDocument?

Tags: php, dom

I need to click a button in a remote page loaded using loadHTMLFile, like in javascript.
It is possible? Something like:

```
$domObject->getElementById('clickableButton')->click();
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that with DOMDocument.  It's a DOM parser, not a JavaScript engine or a headless browser.

Comment: No, it's not possible in DOMDocument.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to let the php script login to a different page, unfortunately, the page is in aspx, so I can't submit the form in any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have loaded the page in the DOM, it's just a bunch of strings divided in objects. So answer is no - DOM in PHP can't parse and run javascript code.

However, if you're trying to submit a form, you can make GET/POST request to the URL given in action attribute of the form element. Try using cURL, or just `file_get_contents` may do the trick.